# onNewIntent in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am recieving some text from other apps, for example if people share a video from youtube app, my app will show up in the shareable list. If they choose my app, I want to get the text content.

I have an intent-filter like this.

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:host="*" android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

I can access the data using the `onNewIntent` method from the activity.

```kotlin
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    Log.d(TAG, intent?.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT).toString())
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
}
```

But I want to access the text inside a composable function, how can I do that?

Comment: You could update an activity-scoped viewmodel from `onNewIntent()`, and have it make the data available via `MutableState`, `StateFlow`, `LiveData`, or whatever. You would then need to pass that viewmodel into your root composable (the one you set up with `setContent()`) so that child composables can observe the results.

Comment: My suggestion would be to add a (preferably delegated) MutableState property to your Activity class and pass that into the composable. If you use ViewModel you have to deal with different lifecycles, as the ViewModel tends to outlive the Activity. You'd typically want to set the property from both onCreate() and onNewIntent().

Answer (score 7):

I think using a disposable effect in the `setContent` method should do the work

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DisposableEffect(Unit) {
                val listener = Consumer<Intent> {
                    // logic here
                }
                addOnNewIntentListener(listener)
                onDispose { removeOnNewIntentListener(listener) }
            }
        }
    }
```